# Laravel join use to get one to many relations?

Tags: mysql, laravel, join

Is there any way to get relational data ( one to many relation records ) using joins in laravel without creating different records in collection :

Example:

```
 $orders  = DB::table('orders')
                     ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.users_id')
                     ->join('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                     ->select('users.*', 'order_items.*')
                     ->get();
```

So here what's happening is that its creating 6 records if order has 6 items but i want something like single records in which it has array or collection where are order items are listed.

Output I want is generally of this order:

```
Collection {# ▼
  #items: array:[▼
          0 => {
            +'id':1,
              ...,
            + 'items: [
                     //here i want all the records of relation order items
           ]
      }
 ]
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this result without using **with()** or **load()** and just only with joins or raw queries?

Comment: Please include the raw MySQL query which you want to do here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sorry mate but I am aasking how I can achieve this result. I have nothing in mind right now. :-(

Comment: We can certainly write this using a raw query, just tell us what output you want.

Comment: `without using with() or load()` why ? it's exactly the aim of using it. By pure SQL, you will always have as many rows as joined table have. Using Eloquent will solve your thing

Comment: @VincentDecaux actually I am not using eloquent models for the record fetching processing due to need a lot of joining operations like joining 8-9 table with parent table but facing problem with order items. As I am fetching huge records like more 100k at time.

Comment: You should learn about Laravel better : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading, the Framework includes Lazy loading, you will not do better using Raw queries

Comment: @VincentDecaux will it effect my processing time if I use 9 relations with eager loading in place of joins to fetch and process data

Comment: Of course, do you think you are the first one with many relations and many rows to load ? that's why eager loading exists, and this is a framework part. Try it, but it will make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$orders  = DB::table('orders')
                     ->select('users.*', 'order_items.*')
                     ->leftJoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.users_id')
                     ->leftJoin('order_items', 'order_items.order_id', '=', 'orders.id')
                     ->get();
```

Comment: Thats what I am doing but its not working. Its creating as much records as much items are in order_items reated to that order.E.g if 3 items of order then its creating 3 records for that order in the fetched collection.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is speculative, but perhaps you want to report a single row for each user, with a CSV list of order items:

```
$orders = DB::table('orders AS o')
    ->join('users AS u', 'u.id', '=', 'o.users_id')
    ->join('order_items AS oi', 'oi.order_id', '=', 'o.id')
    ->select('u.id', DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(oi.name) AS orders'))
    ->groupBy('u.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Its working but DB::raw('GROUP_CONCAT(oi.name) AS orders') is giving the right format data as its giving single columns and concatenating multiple columns in string, as this format will not work as need like 10 columns from table so I asked for collection or array format. But still thanks it still an upgrade.Stil cann't upvote.. Sorry mate

Answer (score -2):

If there's no reason stopping you from using the `Eloquent`, is the best way for working with databases.

> The Eloquent ORM included with Laravel provides a beautiful, simple
>   ActiveRecord implementation for working with your database

Here is the Documentation [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent)

The model relationship made easy in laravel, you can get you want as following:

### The User model relationships:

```
//user orders
public function orders() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
}
```

### The Order model relationships:

```
//order items
public function items() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');
}

//order owner
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

### The OrderItem model relationships:

```
//order
public function order() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
}
```

### Here is a quick example of how you may get the order's items

```
$orders = User::find($id)->orders
foreach($orders as $order) {
    $orderItems = $order->items;
}
```

you can make the collection the way you prefer, but strongly recommend using [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources), since most apps these days expecting JSON responses.

Comment: Yea these relations already exists but I have a lot of relations or related tables and want a centralised result collection without handling a lot of relational collections because have to deal with a huge data records.